# how to specify multiple browserify transforms on the command line?

Tags: browserify, babeljs

How do I specify multiple transforms in browserify using the command-line interface?

Specifically, I'm trying to use `babelify`, `hbsfy` (handlebars), and `coffeeify` (coffeescript).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Specify each transform as a separate `-t [ transform ]` argument. Pay attention to white space in the `-t` options.

```
browserify jsbundle.js \
-t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ] \
-t [ hbsfy ] -t [ coffeeify ] \
--extension=jsx --extension=hbs --extension=coffee
```

Comment: Is that whitespace requirement in the Browserify docs somewhere? Because that's quite an obscure gotcha.